# How can automatically access an embedded device's web server using a network alias over a local LAN?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, network-programming, embedded

I have a embedded linux device I want to build and I want to make it easy for anyone to connect to it. So, when it is first setup, it is connected to the LAN using a WPS button feature.

Now, I want to be able to type in "mymagicbox" in a browser from another PC on the LAN and connect to the web server within the embedded device. How can I design this to do it automatically without having the user change the router settings or lookup the actual device's IP address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) aka ZeroConf

Comment: Thanks, Also saw this question's answer after I searched with bonjour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005136/connect-to-website-on-local-network-without-knowing-ip

Comment: It looks like bonjour requires the .local extension in the name. How do I do this using "mymagicbox" ?